# Lost HTTP custom Header in Redirect response with java servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I have problems to create HTTP headers and send as response to another request page. I've that code;

[image]

In browser inspection, I found:

[image]

but when I go to the redirected page, I don't received that header

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You send a redirect - which won't carry the headers of the original request. See https://httpstatuses.com/303

Make yourself clear what's happening:
your response carries the status code 303, which will trigger the client to create a new request to the url you specified.
And this new request won't contain the prior response's headers.

Comment: Wich http status should i use? Thats is the only problem?

Comment: When using a redirect, you have two options, as far as I know:
add a request param to the redirect url or use a cookie